# Images on glooey buttons (pyglet) sometimes drawn sometimes not

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pyglet, glooey

I have a pyglet mainwindow on which I want to add some control buttons. An icon is drawn on each of these buttons.

Here is my minimalistic example:

```
from PIL import Image
import glooey
import pyglet

class BasicButton(glooey.Button):
    def __init__(self, *, button_text, image_path):
        super().__init__(button_text)
        self.sprite = None
        self.image_path = image_path

    def do_draw(self):
        image_width, image_height = Image.open(self.image_path).size
        x = self.rect.left + self.rect.width/2 - image_width/2
        y = self.rect.bottom + self.rect.height/2 - image_height/2
        if self.sprite is None:
            self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=pyglet.image.load(image_path), 
                                               x=x, y=y, batch=self.batch, group=self.group)
        else:
            self.sprite.x = x
            self.sprite.y = y

class AddWidgetsToWindow(glooey.Widget):
    def __init__(self, pyglet_window: pyglet.window.Window):
        super().__init__()
        self.gui = glooey.Gui(pyglet_window)

        vbox = glooey.VBox(default_cell_size=40)
        vbox.padding = 5
        vbox.alignment = 'left'

        menu_buttons = [
            """
            All buttons listed here
            """
        ]

        for button in menu_buttons:
            vbox.add(button)

        self.gui.add(vbox)

window = pyglet.window.Window()
AddWidgetsToWindow(window)
pyglet.app.run()
```

If I run this a couple of times I always get a different set of properly drawn buttons:

[image]

The question is, why is this happening and how could it be solved?

Comment: Could someone add `glooey` as a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer the original question, but it seems that what OP really wants to do is change the text of a button dynamically (e.g. via a callback).  This is easy to do, and doesn't require overloading any parent class methods.

The important concept to understand is that a button is really just a specialized container of other widgets.  Specifically, a button contains a foreground widget and a handful of background widgets (one for each mouse state).  To change the button dynamically, you just need to access the relevant contained widget (the foreground in this case) and change it.  The nice thing about this architecture is that it works no matter what kind of widgets are in the button.  If the foreground is a `Label`, you can set `button.foreground.text`.  If it's an `Image`, you can set `button.foreground.image`, etc.

Here's an simple but complete example of how to do this.  In this example, the button rollover states are just solid colors instead of images, and the button text is just a number that increments each time the button is clicked, but hopefully it show how to do things like this.

```
import pyglet
import glooey

class MyButton(glooey.Button):
    custom_base_color =  40,  40,  40  # dark grey
    custom_over_color =  80,  80,  80  # normal grey
    custom_down_color = 240, 240, 240  # light grey

window = pyglet.window.Window()
gui = glooey.Gui(window)

# Note that arguments to the Button constructor are passed directly to the 
# constructor of the foreground widget, which is `Text` by default.
button = MyButton('1')
gui.add(button)

def on_click(button):
    i = int(button.foreground.text)
    button.foreground.text = str(i + 1)

button.push_handlers(on_click)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Edit:

I now understand that OP wants a button that has both an image and a label in the foreground (and still has a mouse-responsive background, of course).  The same button-is-a-container concept from above also pertains to this.  A button can only have one foreground widget, but the foreground widget itself can contain any number of widgets.  For example, you could make the foreground an `HBox` to put several widgets side-by-side within a button.

To make a button where the foreground has text on top of an image, the trick is the make the foreground widget a `Stack`.  You can then add the text and the image to that stack.

The example below shows one way to do this.  Note that the foreground stack is factored into its own custom widget class called `MyImageLabel`.  I think this makes the code more clear and reusable, but you can get the same effect without doing this (i.e. by creating the stack directly in `MyButton.Foreground`, or even by creating the stack after the button is instantiated and assigning it to `button.foreground`).  Also note that the text and the image can both be modified via callbacks, in pretty much the same way as above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pyglet
import glooey

class MyImageLabel(glooey.Widget):
    Image = glooey.Image
    Label = glooey.Label

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stack = glooey.Stack()
        self.label = self.Label()
        self.image = self.Image()

        self._stack.add(self.image)
        self._stack.add(self.label)

        self._attach_child(self._stack)

class MyButton(glooey.Button):

    class Foreground(MyImageLabel):

        class Image(MyImageLabel.Image):
            custom_image = pyglet.image.load('img0.png')

        class Label(MyImageLabel.Label):
            custom_text = '1'
            custom_alignment = 'center'

    custom_base_color =  40,  40,  40  # dark grey
    custom_over_color =  80,  80,  80  # normal grey
    custom_down_color = 240, 240, 240  # light grey

window = pyglet.window.Window()
gui = glooey.Gui(window)

button = MyButton()
gui.add(button)

def on_click(button):
    i = int(button.foreground.label.text)
    button.foreground.label.text = str(i + 1)
    button.foreground.image.image = pyglet.image.load(f'img{i%2}.png')

button.push_handlers(on_click)

pyglet.app.run()
```

[image: screenshot]

If you want to run the above example, you'll need to download these images and name them `img0.png` and `img1.png`, respectively:

[image: green border]
[image: orange border]

Comment: This is fine, but could you complete it also with an image on the button's foreground? All other color changes should remain.The text part does not differ much from my implementation (not show in the question).

Comment: Do you mean an image and text in the foreground, or an image instead of text in the foreground?

Comment: I mean a color on the background, and an image and variable text on the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what's going on, but I have a few comments that might be helpful:

- This kind of problem (where images randomly don't show up) is usually a sign that two images are in the same `OrderedGroup`.  This causes the images to be ordered randomly.  When the image that's supposed to be in the back ends up in front, it looks like the image that's supposed to be in the front just isn't there.

  In this case, `self.sprite` is in the same group as the button, so that looks suspicious.
- You probably shouldn't inherit from `Button` and implement `do_draw()`.  The `Button` class is designed to be configured using class variables, like so:

  ```
  class BasicButton(glooey.Button):
      custom_base_image = pyglet.image.load('...')
      custom_over_image = pyglet.image.load('...')
      custom_down_image = pyglet.image.load('...')
  ```

  If you need to implement `do_draw()` for some reason not shown in this simple example, it's probably best to derive a new widget from `Widget` instead of `Button`.  `Button` is basically a configurable `Stack` of `Image`/`Background`/`Label` widgets.  I'd only overload `Button` methods from a subclass if I wanted to do something really unusual with these widgets.   But in this case, `do_draw()` seems like it's not doing anything with these widgets at all; it's just covering them up with an image.  If that's the case, the best thing would be to inherit from `Widget` so that there's nothing to cover up in the first place.  Note that all widgets (not just `Button`) emit events when they're clicked on, and you can use `Rollover` to easily implement rollover effects in custom `Widget` subclasses.
- This is a small thing, but it's a little weird to use PIL to get the width and height on an image.  You can get this information directly from pyglet, e.g.:

  ```
  img = pyglet.image.load(image_path)
  x = self.rect.center.x - img.width / 2
  y = self.rect.center.y - img.height / 2
  ```

If these comments don't help, I can probably give a better answer if you post a code snippet that actually runs (along with the necessary image files) and exhibits the problem.

Comment: Tks for your quite informative answer. By using `Button` as the base class I intended to get the usage of the expected button behavior and at the same time allow me to style it. If I can achieve the same with a `Widget` then I'll try that. I tried your suggestions using the `custom..image` shortly and it worked. But the whole style I had created vanished obviously.

Answer (score 0):

@Kale Kundert definitely send me on the right direction to solve this issue. Yes the group order is fundamental and with a little help from this documentation: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/graphics/ I managed to get the desired behavior by making sure the `Sprite` object in my implementation is added to the foreground group as:

```
class BasicButton(glooey.Button):
    def __init__(self, *, button_text, image_path):
        super().__init__(button_text)
        self.sprite = None
        self.image_path = image_path

    def do_draw(self):
        image_width, image_height = Image.open(self.image_path).size
        x = self.rect.left + self.rect.width/2 - image_width/2
        y = self.rect.bottom + self.rect.height/2 - image_height/2
        if self.sprite is None:
            self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(
                img=pyglet.image.load(image_path), 
                x=x, y=y, 
                batch=self.batch, 
                group=self._foreground.get_group()
        )
        else:
            self.sprite.x = x
            self.sprite.y = y
```

Note the change on `self._foreground.get_group()`.

Considering the answer from @Kale Kundert, maybe this is not the most correct implementation, but with it I aimed at getting the behavior of a button with a responsive background on hoovering/clicking, which also allows me to edit text displayed on it via a callback. I could not achieve this level of freedom if I add to create button icons (images) for every potential situation.